# Catch error when using populate with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the next model and route with mongoose:

In my colection I have some invalids id's to "cidade" field and this is why I am getting the error showing below.

The error happens in the line:

```
.populate('cidade')
```

Is there a way to execute my router(code is below) in:

```
router.get('/:id',function(req,res,next){  .....
```

without stop on that error?
If an invalid "id" is found, I´d just like to ignore it and proceed to next.

My collections are too big and can have some invalids "ids" to "cidade" field.

//error

```
angular.js:14328 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"Ararendá\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Cidade\"","name":"CastError","stringValue":"\"Ararendá\"","kind":"ObjectId","value":"Ararendá","path":"_id"},"status":500,"config":
```

//models and route

//cidade

```
cidadesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  uf: {type: String, unique:true},
  cidade: {type: String, unique:true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Cidade', cidadesSchema,'cidades' );
```

//profiss

```
var profissionaisSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nome: {type: String, unique:true},
  cidade: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Cidade'},
  estado: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Estado'},
  cep: {type: String},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Profissional', profissionaisSchema,'profissionais' );
```

//route

```
const callback=function(err,data,res){
     if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
     return res.status(200).send(data);
}   
router.get('/:id',function(req,res,next){   
    const query=req.params.id;
    Profissional.findById(query).populate('profissao')
    .populate('cidade')
    .exec( (err,data) => {
       callback(err,data,res)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can tell Mongoose to just ignore those errors *and* keep going, so you're going to have to implement the population yourself (which should be relatively easy because you're using `findById` which would only yield, at most, one document).

Here's some (untested) code:

```
Profissional.findById(query).populate('profissao').exec( (err, profi) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).json(err);
  } else if (! profi || ! /^[a-f0-9]{24}$/i.test(profi.cidade)) {
    return res.status(200).send(profi);
  }
  Cidade.findById(profi.cidade).exec((err, cidade) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
    profi.cidade = cidade;
    return res.status(200).send(profi);
  });
});
```

If the `cidade` property looks like a valid ObjectId, it will run a query to retrieve it, otherwise it won't bother.

Comment: Thank you for your help.